# A simple database version control

Tags: sql, version-control

If you have a table which stores questions *and* answers, for example using an extra column called something such as Parent. So if a question doesn't have a value in parent, it's a question and if it does, its a reply, so how would you do version control for this?

Comment: Sounds like a hierarchical comment thread. What do you mean by "version control"? You want to see what the "tree" looked like at some point in the past?

Comment: If someone posts a reply, then they change their reply, then they wanted to go back to their previous answer...that sort of thing.

Comment: That design sounds a bit hinky. Might I suggest a separate table for Questions and Answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a well-developed example of how to keep past revisions of text, you could look at the [MediaWiki database layout](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDatabase_layout). This is the database layout used by the MediaWiki software, which many wikis (notably Wikipedia) run on. Specifically, the `page`, `revision`, and `text` tables are the primary tables involved with keeping track of historic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have one table for questions, and a separate one for answers:

Here's an example in SQLite

The questions table should contain the text of the question and an id field to join on:

```
sqlite3
sqlite> CREATE TABLE questions(id, question);
sqlite> INSERT INTO questions VALUES(1,"What is your name");
sqlite> INSERT INTO questions VALUES(2,"Phone Number");
sqlite> INSERT INTO questions VALUES(3,"name of dog")
sqlite> SELECT * FROM questions;
1|What is your name
2|Phone Number
```

The answers should contain a revision number or date, the text of the answer, a field to indicate which user is asked the question (if necessary), and the id of the question to which it is an answer.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE answers(question,userid,revision,answer);
sqlite> INSERT INTO answers VALUES(1,100,1,"Alex");
sqlite> INSERT INTO answers VALUES(2,100,1,"1234");
sqlite> INSERT INTO answers VALUES(2,100,2,"5678");
sqlite> SELECT * from answers;
1|100|1|Alex
2|100|1|1234
2|100|2|5678
```

Now query on the two databases, making sure that:  only the most recent revision is selected (GROUP and MAX), and unanswered questions are included (LEFT JOIN)

```
sqlite> SELECT questions.question, answers.answer, userid, max(revision) 
                FROM questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.question
                GROUP BY questions.id, userid;
What is your name|Alex|100|1
Phone Number|5678|100|2
name of dog|||
```

You can create some other queries to list past answers for a given question/user, and to list unanswered questions by user.